# Will Force.com stop working on salesforce Lightning?

Tags: visualforce, lightning, community, force.com, site.com

I would like to know if the October 2019 switch from salesforce classic to lightning. Will the force.com pages stop working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. The change from Classic to Lightning only affects internal users, and not Communities and other external-facing technologies. Visualforce is still a supported technology and will be for the foreseeable future. We will not be forced to switch to Lightning Communities, etc for some time. Removing the Classic interface is a decision to reduce development costs and expenditures, allowing more resources to be dedicated to new features.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Would you have any salesforce documentation talking about?
I searched more I did not find.

Comment: @HenriqueArguto As far as force.com/site.com/etc, there's not a lot of docs on it, because it is *not* affected. The lack of documentation is the real key. That said, check out [the site](http://lightningtransitionlearningmap.com/) that explains everything there is to know about migrating to Lightning.

Comment: Thank you very much.